# Can't detect click on links generated by jQuery

Tags: jquery-selectors

I'm generating some links for pagination of some data.

Here's the function that generates the links:

```
function BuildPaginationNav(targetPage, pageSize) {

    var numRecords = $('#movieListTable').children().length,
    numPages = Math.ceil(numRecords / pageSize),
    startRecord = ((targetPage - 1) * pageSize);

    for (var i = startRecord; i <= startRecord + pageSize - 1; i++) {
        $('div#movieListTable > div:eq(' + i + ')').fadeIn(200);
    }

    // Only use prev page and first page buttons/links if not on first page
    if (targetPage > 1) { 
        $('#pagination').append('<br><a href="#" id="firstPage">First Page</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#" id="prevPage">Prev Page</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;');
    } else if (targetPage = 1) {
        $('#pagination').append('<br>First Page&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;Prev Page&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;');
    }

    // Add the current page label
    $('#pagination').append('<label id="currentPage">' + targetPage + '</label>');

    // Only use next page and last page buttons/links if not on last page
    if (targetPage < numPages) {
        $('#pagination').append('&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#" id="nextPage">Next Page</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#" id="lastPage">Last Page</a>');
    } else if ( targetPage === numPages) {
        $('#pagination').append('&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;Next Page&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;Last Page');
    }
}
```

The above works as intended and the function is called at the end of the success function in an $.ajax call that gets the data that the pagination is for.

Here's what the generated HTML looks like if it's not on the first or last page:

```
<div id="pagination">
    <br>
    <a href="#" id="firstPage">First Page</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <a href="#" id="prevPage">Prev Page</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <label id="currentPage">2</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <a href="#" id="nextPage">Next Page</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <a href="#" id="lastPage">Last Page</a>
</div>
```

What I need to do is get the ID of the link that is clicked on so I can take the appropriate action. I've tried this:

```
$('#pagination a').click(function() {
    console.log(this.id);
});
```

and I've also tried this:

```
$('#pagination a').on('click', function() {
    console.log(this.id);
});
```

But neither works - well, if I put the generated HTML and the above jQuery in a jsFiddle it **does** work, but it doesn't in the full code.

I am especially surprised that $.on() doesn't work in this case, as I use that function elsewhere in my code.

If I put the generated HTML as HTML in the page itself, the jQuery **does** work, so it's got to have something with the fact that the links are generated dynamically.

How can I get clicks on those links to be detected?

Answer (score 0):

Your links are not created yet when binding event. You need to bind live action on some existing element.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#pagination").on('click', 'a', function() { .... });

});
```

The '#pagination' element is supposed to be available in time of binding event. It's called delegated event - http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

I found the function $.delegate();

I added this code at the end of the BuildPaginationNav() function:

```
$('#pagination').delegate('a', 'click', function() { console.log(this.id); });
```

I'll just call a function from there (where the console.log() is) that will perform the necessary actions.

If there's a different (or even better) way, let me know!

Answer (score 0):

I would have done it in following way.

Your way:

```
 // Only use prev page and first page buttons/links if not on first page
    if (targetPage > 1) { 
        $('#pagination').append('<br><a href="#" id="firstPage">First Page</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#" id="prevPage">Prev Page</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;');
    } else if (targetPage = 1) {
        $('#pagination').append('<br>First Page&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;Prev Page&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;');
    }
```

My Way:

```
 // Only use prev page and first page buttons/links if not on first page
    if (targetPage > 1) { 
$FirstPage=$('<a href="#" id="firstPage">First Page</a>');
$FirstPage.click(function() { .... });
$('#pagination').append($FirstPage);

        //same for Prev page...
    } else if (targetPage = 1) {
       // same as above..
    }
```

This way...i'm able to locate my links behaviour at one place only i do not need to search in the whole page to know.. what click event for anchors..and many more !!